# Customizing UITabbar Customization Modal View Controller

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

There are 9 UITabBarItems in my iOS 7 application. It supports customisation of tabbar items in the application (re oredering of Tab bar items).

When I perform order customization of Tab Bar Items, iOS will present a modal viewcontroller from the TabBar for dragging and arranging of Tab bars. Is there any way to customize this modally presented viewcontroller ?

Thanks in Advance.